# How to remove quotes from list of strings and store it as list again..?

Tags: python, string, list, double-quotes, single-quotes

I have to call the function in a for loop. All those functions are stored in a list as a string with quotes. I need to remove those quotes and store the values again in a list.

What needs to be done:

1. Fetch the function list from DB
2. Remove single/double quotes from a list of strings
3. Store those strings in a list
4. Loop the list to execute functions

**Python**

```
fruits = ['apple','mango','orange']
print(type(fruits))
func = '[%s]'%','.join(map(str,fruits))
print(func) ## [apple,mango,orange]
print(type(func))

def apple():
  print("In apple")
def mango():
   print("In mango")
def orange():
   print("In orange")

n = len(func)
func_it = itertools.cycle(func)
for i in range(n):
   next(func_it)()
```

**Output**

```
<class 'list'>
[apple,mango,orange]
<class 'str'>
```

After removing the quotes from the strings, Its data type is getting changed to .
Is there any way to remove quotes from a list of strings and store those values as a list again?

Comment: I don't think it's possible because list remove quotes from string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built in python exec() function that will execute any string as code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

fruits = ['apple','mango','orange']

def apple():
  print("In apple")
def mango():
   print("In mango")
def orange():
   print("In orange")

for func in fruits:
    exec(func + '()')
```

Output

```
In apple
In mango
In orange
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't call functions like that. Removing quotes from a string won't turn it into a function. You are constructing `func` to be `'[apple, mango, orange]'` which is a string. When you iterate over that you get each of the characters of the string. i.e you get `[`, `a` etc. Each is a string & you can't call strings. You're basically doing `'['()` which is meaningless.

Remember - in Python - functions are first-class objects. If you want to list over functions just put references to those functions in a list:

```
import itertools

def apple():
  print("In apple")
def mango():
   print("In mango")
def orange():
   print("In orange")

func = [apple, mango, orange]  # list of functions
n = len(func)
func_it = itertools.cycle(func)
for i in range(n):
    x = next(func_it)
    print(type(x))  # check the type
    x()
```

Which results in:

```
<class 'function'>
In apple
<class 'function'>
In mango
<class 'function'>
In orange
```

So if you want to construct this list from your string `'[apple, mango, orange]'` you need to `eval` it:

```
s = '[apple, mango, orange]'
func = eval(s)
print(func)
```

Which results in:

```
[<function apple at 0x000001FB9E7CF040>, <function mango at 0x000001FB9ECB7940>, <function orange at 0x000001FB9ECB7DC0>]
```

However if possible you should always try to avoid using `eval`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code i'm guessing you want to call a function based on a string? I suggest using a dictionary

```
import itertools
fruits = ['apple','mango','orange']
def apple():
  print("In apple")
def mango():
   print("In mango")
def orange():
   print("In orange")
funcs = {'apple':apple()}
funcs['apple']
```

out

```
In apple
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `globals()` to get the function object using name then you can use that object

```
func = [globals()[fun] for fun in fruits]
func_it = itertools.cycle(func)
for i in range(len(func)):
   next(func_it)()
```

**Output:**

```
In apple
In mango
In orange
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, the line `hehe = eval(func)` creates a list of the names which are later taken as function calls and it's possible because the ending parentheses "()" are not necessary, atleast in Python 3.9.

```
import itertools

def apple():
  print("In apple")
def mango():
   print("In mango")
def orange():
   print("In orange")

fruits = ['apple','mango','orange']
print(type(fruits))
func = '[%s]'%','.join(map(str,fruits))
print(func) ## [apple,mango,orange]
hehe = eval(func)
print(type(hehe))

n = len(hehe)
func_it = itertools.cycle(hehe)
for i in range(n):
   next(func_it)()
```

output:

```
<class 'list'>
[apple,mango,orange]
<class 'list'>
In apple
In mango
In orange
```